# Getting a block-scope error when declaring functions inside of main()

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that will generate random numbers for a bunch of message boxes, and then blue screen. Don't worry, it doesn't actually hurt anyone's files or programs. I have been unable to run my program because `WinEventProc` has an error that says `a block-scope function may only have extern storage class`. I have been declaring my functions inside of main. In other words, I have been putting my whole program inside of `main()`, so I'm wondering if I can't do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include "Uh_Oh.h"
using namespace std;
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* pdef_NtRaiseHardError)(NTSTATUS ErrorStatus, ULONG NumberOfParameters, ULONG UnicodeStringParameterMask OPTIONAL, PULONG_PTR Parameters, ULONG ResponseOption, PULONG Response);
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* pdef_RtlAdjustPrivilege)(ULONG Privilege, BOOLEAN Enable, BOOLEAN CurrentThread, PBOOLEAN Enabled);

int main()
{
    // Random #'s generated and put in variables
    random_device dev;
    mt19937 rng(dev());
    uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> distx(1, 1920); // distribution for x in range [1, 1920]
    uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> disty(1, 1080); // distribution for y in range [1, 1080]
    int randomx;
    int randomy;
    randomx = distx(rng);
    randomy = disty(rng);
    thread_local int MsgBox_X;
    thread_local int MsgBox_Y;

    static void CALLBACK WinEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
    {
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, MsgBox_X, MsgBox_Y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    }

    int MessageBoxPos(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType, int X, int Y)
    {
        HWINEVENTHOOK hHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, NULL, &WinEventProc, GetCurrentProcessId(), GetCurrentThreadId(), WINEVENT_INCONTEXT);
        MsgBox_X = X;
        MsgBox_Y = Y;
        int result = MessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
        if (hHook)  UnhookWinEvent(hHook);
        return result;
    }

    void _MessageBox()
    {
        UhOh = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
        // ... call same MessageBoxPos function a bunch of more times
        // UhOh2
        // UhOh3
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));

    typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* pdef_NtRaiseHardError)(NTSTATUS ErrorStatus, ULONG NumberOfParameters, ULONG UnicodeStringParameterMask OPTIONAL, PULONG_PTR Parameters, ULONG ResponseOption, PULONG Response);
    typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* pdef_RtlAdjustPrivilege)(ULONG Privilege, BOOLEAN Enable, BOOLEAN CurrentThread, PBOOLEAN Enabled);
    BOOLEAN bEnabled;
    ULONG uResp;
    LPVOID lpFuncAddress = GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("ntdll.dll"), "RtlAdjustPrivilege");
    LPVOID lpFuncAddress2 = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtRaiseHardError");
    pdef_RtlAdjustPrivilege NtCall = (pdef_RtlAdjustPrivilege)lpFuncAddress;
    pdef_NtRaiseHardError NtCall2 = (pdef_NtRaiseHardError)lpFuncAddress2;
    NTSTATUS NtRet = NtCall(19, TRUE, FALSE, &bEnabled);
    NtCall2(STATUS_FLOAT_MULTIPLE_FAULTS, 0, 0, 0, 6, &uResp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to define a function inside another function. You can't do that in C++.

Comment: Why do you want to create the BSOD (Blue Screen Of Death)?

Comment: @Raymond Chen I see.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews It’s for a fun little project. It would be cool for something like April fools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move all this code:

```
static void CALLBACK WinEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, MsgBox_X, MsgBox_Y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
}

int MessageBoxPos(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType, int X, int Y)
{
    HWINEVENTHOOK hHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, NULL, &WinEventProc, GetCurrentProcessId(), GetCurrentThreadId(), WINEVENT_INCONTEXT);
    MsgBox_X = X;
    MsgBox_Y = Y;
    int result = MessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
    if (hHook)  UnhookWinEvent(hHook);
    return result;
}

void _MessageBox()
{
    UhOh = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh2 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh3 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh4 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh5 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh6 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh7 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh8 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh9 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh10 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh11 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh12 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh13 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh14 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh15 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh16 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh17 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh18 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh19 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);
    UhOh20 = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Uh Oh!"), TEXT("Your computer ran out of memory! Windows will now crash."), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK, randomx, randomy);

}
```

before the line

```
int main()
```

You cannot define functions inside of other functions.

Comment: "*You cannot define functions inside of other functions*" - no, but you can define lambdas inside of functions, and non-capturing lambdas are convertible to function pointers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau totally separate issue, is there a good canonical Q&A for 'whats a smart pointer and when and how should I use them', the number of times it comes up, its a pain retyping the answers

Comment: @RemyLebeau While technically true, it's also just going to create confusion for a beginner. Best not to introduce lambdas yet.